Unable to establish connection between elastic search and curator
Both my elastic search and curator are deployed in the same Kubernetes cluster and same namespace. I have given the elastic hostname, port and http auth in username and password in curator config file for connecting to elastic search.
But when I am running the curator job I could see it is defaulting to local host. So I tried connecting using cluster DNS still it is the same
Note: My elastic search is exposed as NodePort. Hence given the hostname accordingly.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/elastic_transport/_transport.py", line 342, in perform_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/elastic_transport/_node/_http_urllib3.py", line 202, in perform_request
elastic_transport.ConnectionError: Connection error caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5c78b74cd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
2024-04-21 09:05:18,198 INFO      GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/ [status:N/A duration:0.000s]
2024-04-21 09:05:18,198 WARNING   Node <Urllib3HttpNode(http://127.0.0.1:9200)> has failed for 4 times in a row, putting on 8 second timeout
2024-04-21 09:05:18,198 CRITICAL  Unable to establish client connection to Elasticsearch!
2024-04-21 09:05:18,198 CRITICAL  Exception encountered: Connection error caused by: ConnectionError(Connection error caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5c79554390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refuse


client:
      hosts: 
        - <my_cluster_master_hostname>
      port: <nodeport>
      url_prefix:
      use_ssl: False
      certificate:
      client_cert:
      client_key:
      ssl_no_validate: False
      http_auth: "username:password"
      timeout: 30
      master_only: False

Note:
Elastic search version: 7.17.9
Curator version: curator:8.0.14

I would like to successfully connect to my elastic search deployed inside my cluster from the curator and manage the indices but every time it is defaulting to local host and elastic is not deployed there. Hence unable to manage elastic-indices.

I have tried explicitly configuring the host and port along with credentials in the curator config file.
I also tried to connect using Kubernetes DNS Service Discovery.

None of the methods worked out.
Note: I am able to connect to my elastic search using elastic view using the same URL and authentication and also hit it in browser and getting response as expected

Not sure if your configuration is correct, but if you are trying to connect internally within the same cluster I suggest configuring the hostname in accordance to DNS resolution within the same cluster.
So if the namespace where elasticsearch is called 'es' and the K8s service where elasticsearch is exposed is called 'elastic' the DNS name for your cluster will be: elastic.es.svc.cluster.local. Your config will look something like this:
hosts: 
  - elastic.es.svc.cluster.local
port: 9200

Note this is the default configuration for coredns within the cluster.

More of a comment here than an answer, but you’re trying to use Curator 8 with Elasticsearch 7. It may or may not work, but it definitely will not unless you add the skip_version_test flag to other_settings and set it to true.
Curator is at 8.0.15 now. Also, since 8.0.11, you can exclusively use environment variables for client configuration, no config file required.
